# How do I change .install4j directory to other directory

Tags: install4j

I use install4j to package my Java program.
But I find there is a .install4j directory in my installer directory .
I don't want my customer to know that I use install4j to package the programme.
How do I change this directory to another name,such as .john directory .

Answer (score 1):

As of 5.1.6, it is not possible to change the name of this runtime directory.

Comment: You mean it could be changed in old version ?Which version can I change the name of runtime directory?

Comment: As a consumer,I think I can change this directory as I wish since I pay for it.

Comment: You can change the name of the directory, but then the installer launchers and the uninstaller will not find the runtime anymore.